# Excel Add-In: How to programmatically deselect a region?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010, office-interop

After my code performs a copy & special paste of a whole external worksheet into the current workbook, the target remains selected. It seems than in the past there was a .Deselect() function?

I have attempted to select the cell [1,1], but the app crashes with a COM error.

For reference, this is one of many sites that provide methods that fail to work:

```
 https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/programmatically-deselect-a-selection.2412034/
```

TIA

Comment: It's literally impossible for us to answer the issue if you don't give us the specific error and the specific code.

Comment: You don't need to select a range to copy it. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).  Do you mean that you want to set `Application.CutCopyMode = False` ?  

Also, [it's almost impossible to advise further without details of your code, and the error.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: Olly: The Application.CutPasteMode = false statement only works for BASIC. In C# it is an enumeration of modes, none of them are "off" or "false".

Comment: Rawrplus: You are 100% correct. I was looking for the COM specific COM error code, but my Internet went down last night. Will add it from the office later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select another range/cell if you want to deselect another region.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select();
```

Comment: Thanks, the following approach also works: worksheet.get_Range("A1").Select();